# Connect Four Java Rows Code Not Working

Tags: java

I need to finish this connect four game that I made. It seems like the rows don't work for some reason that I don't know. Here is my code for the rows. When I run my code, the game doesn't stop after getting 4 in a row, but it does stop when I get 4 in a column or in a diagnol. All of the other possibilities do work using this formatting. Here is an example of my columns. This works:

```
public boolean win_col() {
    int xTemp = x;
    int yTemp = y;
    int win = 0;
    while (xTemp != 6) {
        if (A[xTemp][yTemp] == cod) {
            win ++;
            xTemp ++;
        }
        else
            break;

        if (win == 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do with my rows.

```
public boolean win_row() {
    int xTemp = x;
    int yTemp = y;
    int win = 0;
    while (yTemp != 0) {
        if (A[xTemp][yTemp] == cod) {
                win ++;
                yTemp --;
        }
        else 
            break;
        if (win == 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    yTemp = y + 1;
    while (yTemp != 7) {
        if (A[xTemp][yTemp] == cod) {
            win ++;
            yTemp ++;
        }
        else 
            break;
        if (win == 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've been doing this and my rows don't work. Everything but rows work in my program. HELP!!

Comment: Your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Comment: If you want us to help, meet us half way. Don't make us walk to where you're standing. Format your code like those have said, and elaborate more on what you mean by rows not working because that's too ambiguous.

Comment: Tell me if there's any more details you guys need.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger, and the answer should be fairly clear. Probably an off-by-one error or similar.

Comment: @DNA I feel like there's something wrong with my algorithm

Comment: What is x and y, the position of the piece that just got dropped? If so, and to try and understand your code a bit more, how come you traverse backwards for rows but you don't traverse backwards for the column?

Comment: @user3685648 If you "feel" like there is something wrong with your algorithm perhaps debugging it could turn that "feeling" into fact... asking random internet programmers what is wrong is no substitute for debugging your own code!

Comment: @cYn I have my pieces in a double array and the x and y are where the pieces are. For the rows, I'm trying to do that because I'm checking left to right and right to left (doing this because a piece can land in the middle and get a connect four). As for columns, I don't need to because you can't put a piece in the middle

Comment: @MattCoubrough For me, my algorithm seems correct but the code isn't working. What else could be the fault for it to not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand how you're checking for win scenarios so here is a simple way that I would debug without having to work the IDE's debugger, which seems like you don't have much experience in using.

In every state, add a `System.out.println` to see if the code actually behaves the way it should. I would do something like

```
public boolean win_row() {
    int xTemp = x;
    int yTemp = y;
    int win = 0;
    while (yTemp != 0) {
        if (A[xTemp][yTemp] == cod) {
                win ++;
                yTemp --;
                System.out.println("Going Left: Matched");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Going Left: Not Matched");
            break;
        }
        if (win == 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    yTemp = y + 1;
    while (yTemp != 7) {
        if (A[xTemp][yTemp] == cod) {
            win ++;
            yTemp ++;
            System.out.println("Going Right: Matched");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Going Right: Not Matched");
            break;
        }
        if (win == 4) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can also use `System.out.println` to track all of your variables to see if it's actually incrementing/decrementing the way it should in every state that it goes through.

Comment: This is the best anyone's given me. Thanks for the tip. If you want to take a closer look at my game and understand it more, I can give it to you. It's fairly simple and a bit incomplete though, but I'm not asking you to take it and fix it for me. Thanks anyway